# Get the entire CSV line on error parsing or reading

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

Get the entire Csv Line on parsing error

With [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) we use :

> #### `MissingFieldFound`:
>
> Gets or sets the function that is called when a missing field is found.The default 
>   function will throw a CsvHelper.MissingFieldException.You can supply your own 
>   function to do other things like logging the issue instead of throwing an exception. 
>   Arguments: headerNames, index, context
>
> #### `BadDataFound`:
>
> Gets or sets the function that is called when bad field data is found. A field
>   has bad data if it contains a quote and the field is not quoted (escaped). You
>   can supply your own function to do other things like logging the issue instead
>   of throwing an exception. Arguments: context

In the following MCVE, only `MissingFieldFound` capture the complete line when `BadDataFound` did not.

```
static void Main()
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("FirstName,LastName");
        writer.WriteLine("\"Jon\"hn\"\",\"Doe\"");
        writer.WriteLine("\"JaneDoe\"");
        writer.WriteLine("\"Jane\",\"Doe\"");
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;

        var good = new List<Test>();
        var bad = new List<string>();
        var isRecordBad = false;

        csv.Configuration.BadDataFound = context =>
        {
            isRecordBad = true;
            bad.Add(context.RawRecord);
        };

        csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = (headerNames, index, context) =>
        {
            isRecordBad = true;
            bad.Add(context.RawRecord);
        };

        while (csv.Read())
        {
            var record = csv.GetRecord<Test>();
            if (!isRecordBad)
            {
                good.Add(record);
            }

            isRecordBad = false;
        }

        good.Dump();
        bad.Dump();
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I would like the result to be :

> "Jon"hn"","Doe"
>   "JaneDoe"

Instead of :

> "Jon"hn"", 
>   "JaneDoe"

For long Csv with a lot of column the rest of the line often have valuable information.

Comment: Hacky, but you might be able to wrap that `StreamReader` in your own `TextReader` implementation, so you can hold on to the last line read by `CsvReader`. Assuming it takes a `TextReader`, that is - I've never used csvhelper.

Comment: Why don't you contribute the change you want to the CsvHelper GitHub: https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis, Yep `CsvReader` take `TextReader`: `CsvReader(TextReader reader)`. But even if I'm a bit scared about the "_own `TextReader` implementation_" Weekend is in few hour I can read one or two book. Do youi have a documentation/book that can help me in this process.

Comment: @Polyfun, I hoped someone would point me to a property I missed in context or in the stream, reader part. and I would just have to convert from a byte[] and voila. It's the case most of the time.

Comment: @xdtTransform This blog already keeps track of the current/last line: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2005/08/06/deriving-from-textreader/

Comment: Here is the archived version of that post https://web.archive.org/web/20190127101819/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2005/08/06/deriving-from-textreader/

Answer (score 1):

You can get the line with this:

```
 csv.Parser.Context.RawRecord;
```

Comment: That's the same as `context.RawRecord`, that you can see in `csv.Configuration.BadDataFound = context => { isRecordBad = true; bad.Add(context.RawRecord); };`

Comment: As stated in the question it will work in `MissingFieldFound`. But not in `BadDataFound` When the parser get to `BadDataFound` it stop its parsing. Current will only show what was good. In the current version the parser can not recover from it. And won't let you continue the CSV line. Anything using `csv.Parser` won't work in this particular case.

Comment: Seems to be `csv.Parser.RawRecord` in newer versions of CsvReader